# Loading Mondiran Schema to Jasper Report Server: Access denied

Tags: jasperserver, jaspersoft-studio

I am using Jasper Studio v6.3.0 with JasperReports Server Community Edittion v6.3.0 on Windows 2008 Server 64 bit.

When I try to upload my Mondrian schema XML-file to the server, I get next error from:

```
org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: access.denied
Access is denied

    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.restv2.RESTv2ExceptionHandler.handleErrorDescriptor(RESTv2ExceptionHandler.java:118)

    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.restv2.RESTv2ExceptionHandler.handleException(RESTv2ExceptionHandler.java:76)

    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.restv2.ARestV2ConnectionJersey.toObj(ARestV2ConnectionJersey.java:57)

    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.restv2.RestV2ConnectionJersey.addOrModifyResource(RestV2ConnectionJersey.java:557)

    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.ProxyConnection.addOrModifyResource(ProxyConnection.java:336)

    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.WSClientHelper.saveResource(WSClientHelper.java:323)

    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.WSClientHelper.saveResource(WSClientHelper.java:277)
....
```

[image]

How can I fix it?

**Upd, full error stack:**

```
org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: access.denied
Access is denied

    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.restv2.RESTv2ExceptionHandler.handleErrorDescriptor(RESTv2ExceptionHandler.java:118)

    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.restv2.RESTv2ExceptionHandler.handleException(RESTv2ExceptionHandler.java:76)

    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.restv2.ARestV2ConnectionJersey.toObj(ARestV2ConnectionJersey.java:57)

    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.restv2.RestV2ConnectionJersey.addOrModifyResource(RestV2ConnectionJersey.java:557)

    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.ProxyConnection.addOrModifyResource(ProxyConnection.java:336)

    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.WSClientHelper.saveResource(WSClientHelper.java:323)

    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.WSClientHelper.saveResource(WSClientHelper.java:277)

    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.wizard.resource.AddResourceWizard$1.run(AddResourceWizard.java:225)

    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:463)

    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:371)

    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1002)

    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.wizard.resource.AddResourceWizard.performFinish(AddResourceWizard.java:184)

    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:799)

    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:429)

    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)

    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)

    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)

    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)

    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)

    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)

    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)

    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)

    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)

    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.action.resource.AddResourceAction.run(AddResourceAction.java:86)

    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)

    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)

    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)

    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)

    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)

    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)

    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)

    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)

    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)

    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)

    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)

    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)

    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)

    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)

    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)

    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)

    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)

    at com.jaspersoft.studio.rcp.intro.Application.start(Application.java:99)

    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)

    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)

    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)

    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)

    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)

    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)

    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

**Upd 2**, I found that I can't upload any file to Jasper Server, including simple image files:

```
java.lang.Exception: The Server has returned an error with code 1 and with the message Access is denied
    at com.jaspersoft.ireport.jasperserver.ws.WSClient.putReportUnitResource(WSClient.java:617)
    at com.jaspersoft.ireport.jasperserver.ws.WSClient.modifyReportUnitResource(WSClient.java:552)
    at com.jaspersoft.ireport.jasperserver.ws.WSClient.addOrModifyResource(WSClient.java:490)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.soap.SoapConnection.addOrModifyResource(SoapConnection.java:312)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.ProxyConnection.addOrModifyResource(ProxyConnection.java:336)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.WSClientHelper.saveResource(WSClientHelper.java:323)
```

Comment: How do you do the upload? Which language / wrapper? Which user are you using for this upload? What rights / roles has this user set?

Comment: I use Download from System (also I tried download from Workspace with same result), User - standart "joeuser" with ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR, ROLE_USER. language/wrapper- what do you mean?

Comment: I thought you'd use PHP or the like. Usually the admin should be able to write everywhere. Have you copied the whole stacktrace? Did you try with `jasperadmin`?

Comment: I added stacktrace. I can't login jasperadmin in a Jasper Studio.

Comment: Oh that could be a hint. Logging in in Jasperreport Server with jasperadmin works?

Comment: Yes, if I use browser, I can log in as jasperadmin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123843/discussion-between-leo-and-tobi6).